# Change the content of a button using an event handler

Tags: wpf, button

The code contains buttons in datagrid. Each of this contain text "Send".

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" 
                        Header="Uid" 
                        Binding="{Binding Uid}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" 
                        Header="Type" 
                        Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" 
                        Header="ChannelType" 
                        Binding="{Binding ChannelType}"/>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="btnSend" Click="btnSend_Click">Send</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When I click this button, the text "Send" should be changed to "Cancel". How can I do that?

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //If I click first button, only first button should be changed
    //from "Send" to "Cancel"
    //Rest button should remain as "Send"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    changeBtnText((Button)sender, "Cancel");
}

private void changeBtnText(Button button, String text)
{
    if (Button.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        button.Content = text;
    }
    else
    {
        Button.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
        {
            changeBtnText(button);
        });
    }
}
```

You need to put the command in the Dispatcher-Queue as you are modifying the UI, wich only the Dispatcher is allowed to do.